# UIImage by selecting part of another UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, mask

[image]

I have an UIImage and a CGPoint which tells me in what direction I should move it to create another image. The background can be anything.

Give the initial UIImage how I can create the new one? What is the most efficient way of doing it?

Here is what I'm doing:

```
int originalWidth = image.size.width;
int originalHeight = image.size.height;
float xDifference = [[coords objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
float yDifference = [[coords objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];  


UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 240, originalWidth, originalHeight)];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft;

CGRect imageFrame = imageView.frame;
imageFrame.origin.x = xDifference;
imageFrame.origin.y = -yDifference;
imageView.frame = imageFrame;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempView.bounds.size);
[tempView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Is there a more optimal version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use <strike>[CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-SW1)</strike>. You can get a `CGImage` from a `UIImage` with the <strike>[property of the same name](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/CGImage)</strike>.

Basically what you end up doing is apply masks to the existing image to extract the portions you need. Like so -

[image]

```
myImageArea = CGRectMake(xOrigin, yOrigin, myWidth, myHeight);//newImage
mySubimage  = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(oldImage, myImageArea);
myRect      = CGRectMake(0, 0, myWidth*2, myHeight*2);
CGContextDrawImage(context, myRect, mySubimage);
```

[This post](http://stunningco.de/2011/11/19/uiimage-sprite-additions-objective-c/) gives a good idea of how to use this property.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. It was a couple of work hours ago, so I don't clearly remember, but I don't think it was padding the image.

Comment: Yes, but what if the area is not inside the container. I need something that contains the padding too.