# Copy and paste a part of an image

Tags: ios

What i'am trying to do is to program an app where a person can simply copy a part of an image like in photoshop, then paste the content that was copied in where he/she wants on the same picture!
I would be very thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: I think you get answer from this link.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538250/uiimage-by-selecting-part-of-another-uiimage][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538250/uiimage-by-selecting-part-of-another-uiimage

Comment: What is the "same picture" now? UIImageView + UIImage?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand right than you have one image.
and You want to copy it's some small part and past it.

here you can create sub image of your oldImage. myImageArea is a selected image (in form of CGRect)

```
UIImage *CopyImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(oldImage, myImageArea);
```

and you can paste that new image as new UIImage in your view by

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

here x, y, width, height are the paste location.

then

```
imageView.image = CopyImage;
```

And It's done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy whole image then use the following code

```
-(IBAction)copyImageToPasteBoard{
    UIPasteboard *appPasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"CopyFrom" 
             create:YES];
    appPasteBoard.persistent = YES;

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Old-Time-Photo.jpg"]);
    [appPasteBoard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"com.appshop.copyfrom.imagedata"];
}

-(IBAction)pasteImageToPasteBoard{
    UIPasteboard *appPasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"CopyFrom"
             create:YES];
    NSData *data = [appPasteBoard dataForPasteboardType:@"com.appshop.copyfrom.imagedata"];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

Let me know is it useful for you or nor?

Comment: I think the guy needs a way to cut or corp an image