# What is the way to parse a string of a well known format from an image on iOS (some library created specifically for this purpose)?

Tags: ios, api, rest, ocr

Local travel cards in Saint-Petersburg, Russia have got huge id numbers that aren't easy to read and type into a web page when topping up the card online. So I want to build a small app that would take a photo of a travel card and parse the number out.

[image: Podorozhnik travel card]

The task is a bit easier than a free form recognition:

- card is of the very well known size
- id numbers are of known size, are located in the very well known location on a card and they are number only, no letters (okay, there are two variations I think and maybe they will add 1-2 more in the future)
- even the font is known in advance
- even the first several numbers are the same for most of the card (so far there are only two prefixes used)

How would you do it? Are there any libraries tuned not for the general OCR, but for a "hinted" OCR like I need?

Best regards,
Artem.

P.S.

Actually a free/cheap web service for this task would also be good enough

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Google has a library called [Tesseract](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS) and there is an iOS SDK on Github you can import into your application. So you can use this SDK and it has some documentation that you can read that will explain how to set it up in your app. It has methods that will return you a string with the text of the card in the string. BUT it will be ALL of the text from the card. So best thing to do would be to:

**1** "[clip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8538692/3911918)" the original image to extract a sub image that displays *only* the portion of the card you wish to get the numbers from.

**2** Process this sub image through Tesseract to retrieve the string you are looking for.

**3** Then parse through the string and pick out the data that you need.

But just be warned, it can be a bit quirky. This SDK tends to recognize words best from images that are **scanned**, not "taken a picture of". Because although it is an advance piece of technology, it isn't perfect. So to get it to work as perfectly as possible for you, try to get scanned copies of the originals.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution for you would have three components:

1) Detection of the card. This is useful because if you have the detection, then the end users have much easier time actually using the scanner, because they can place the phone above the card in an arbitrary direction

2) Accurate OCR component. Ideally, customizable for this exact font you have on the card, for the exact position on the card.

3) Parsing mechanism. This would enable you to obtain the exact string written on the card without writing huge amount of OCR parsing code.

[BlinkID SDK](https://github.com/blinkid/blinkid-ios) has all this. It has a preset for detection cards in the [ID-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7810) format. It has integrated OCR engine. And it provides RegexParser, where you can define the exact format of the text which you're trying to extract from the document.

BlinkID was initially built for scanning ID documents which have very similar properties as the problem you're trying to solve.

Note. I'm one of the developers working on BlinkID.

Comment: Wow, thanks @Cerovec, indeed it sounds like what I need except that the pricing is "Contact us", not "free/cheap". If the price is in line with MicroBlink's barcode solution ($1.5K per app platform), that would be prohibitive for a hobby-like app with hundreds of users or maybe few thousands if suddenly app gets stunning success.

Does this SDK need online connection or can the recognition happen online? Topping up subway cards is most important exactly when entering subway where connection can be weak.

Comment: The recognition is performed completely offline - no internet connection is needed. The pricing is dependent on the use case - we also have free licensing for noncommercial apps.